# popen - locks or not thread safe?

Tags: locking, thread-safety, popen

I've seen a few implementations of popen()/pclose(). They all used a static list of pids, and no locking:

```
static int *pids;
static int fds;

if (!pids) {
        if ((fds = getdtablesize()) <= 0)
            return (NULL);
        if ((pids = malloc(fds * sizeof(int))) == NULL)
            return (NULL);
        memset(pids, 0, fds * sizeof(int));
    }
```

Or this, supposedly NetBSD:

```
static struct pid {
    struct pid *next;
    FILE *fp;
    pid_t pid;
} *pidlist; 

    /* Link into list of file descriptors. */
    cur->fp = iop;
    cur->pid =  pid;
    cur->next = pidlist;
    pidlist = cur;
```

Is it what it looks like - a not thread safe implementation? Or am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [GNU libc implementation](http://google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en&sa=N&cd=7&ct=rc#HT3Jwvgod1I/glibc-2.5/libio/iopopen.c) is threadsafe if libc is configured to be reentrant (which it is likely to be). However, this may not be the case for other implementations of libc.

Comment: yes, I see it locks the list of children. This is much better. Thanks for the link.

I'd rather popen returned a pid and I passed that to pclose, though, but that's not an option for libc in this case

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you're missing something obvious.  I don't see any reference to thread-safety with popen() either requiring it to be thread-safe or not.  As a result you should probably treat it as non-thread-safe.

Comment: I remember when threads were getting supported, man pages used to tell you explicitly if a function was safe or unsafe. Now I expect a function to be safe it not told otherwise..

Comment: That would be nice.  However - I would reverse your expectation -- functions are generally unsafe unless the author actually thought about the thread issues.  And if it's not mentioned in the man page then they probably didn't think about it.

Comment: At least on Linux, the manpages aren't necessarily written by the glibc folks who write the implementations.

Comment: Posix requires `popen` to be thread safe.  The Posix standard states that all functions are thread safe except, followed by a (very short) list of those that aren't.  `popen` isn't in the list.